# How to prove $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \zeta(s) = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} \zeta(s) = 1$

I have seen a proof using the fact $1 \leq \zeta(s) \leq \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}$ but this relies on proving the inequality first which is quite cumbersome.

I was looking for a proof which is short but easy to understand.

Comment: What do you consider basic? (If you're interested in the $\zeta$-function, integrals should definitely be on the list of basic things.)

Comment: I'm going to edit my post. Usually proofs with integrals are quite long as well

Comment: "Cumbersome"? If this is the proof I think, it is probably the most elementary and direct one that one can imagine.

Comment: It is the one using geometric series. Quite long to include in an essay

Comment: Since you tagged it as [tag:complex-analysis], note that $\zeta$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, so $\lim\limits_{s\to \infty} \zeta(s)$ does not exist. However, $\lim \limits_{\operatorname{Re} s \to +\infty} \zeta(s) = 1$.

Comment: Euler's product formula springs to mind since $1/p^s\to 0$ as $\Re s\to\infty$ for $p$ prime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite your aversion(?) to integrals, I think they give the quickest and easiest argument. The function $n \mapsto n^{-s}$ is decreasing in $n$ (for $s > 1$), so
$$
1 \le \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s} = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n^s} \le 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^s}\,ds = 1 + \frac{1}{s-1}.
$$
To see why the inequality between the series and the integral is valid, draw a picture! Finish off by letting $s \to \infty$ using the squeeze theorem. (This argument assumes that $s$ is real.)

Comment: Integral test for the inequality? Yes I like this proof thanks

Comment: Ah s is real? Is there one for s being a complex number

Comment: $\zeta$ is usually studied as a function of a complex variable, but $\zeta(s)$ doesn't have a limit as $s \to \infty$ as a complex number (since $\zeta$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Upon reading the initial comments I see this is probably the proof the poster already saw but thought was too cumbersome. Oh well here it is:

Let's modify the classic proof that the harmonic series diverges. First we'll note that $\zeta(s)>1$ for large $s$ trivially. Next, note that for $s>1$ we have the following:

$$1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\dots < 1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{4^s} \dots$$

Where we replace $\frac{1}{n^s}$ by $\frac{1}{2^{ks}}$ where $2^k$ is the largest power of 2 less than or equal to $n$. Now combining terms on the right hand side we get:

$$1 +\frac{2}{2^s} + \frac{4}{4^s} +\frac{8}{8^s}+\dots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \big(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\big)^i$$

Finally summing this geometric series gives:

$$\zeta(s) \le \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2^{s-1}-1}$$

Which clearly goes to $1$ as $s$ tends to infinity.

Comment: This is a special case of the Cauchy condensation test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic proof, in the sense that it generalizes to many other kinds of series:

First, note that any partial sum of the series converges:
$$ \lim_{\zeta\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\zeta}=1. $$
This is trivial, as the first term is constant $1$ and the others go to zero.

Second, note that given any fixed $\zeta>1$ and $\varepsilon>0$, you can make the tail small, just by picking $n$ sufficiently large:
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^\zeta}<\varepsilon. $$
This is because the series is convergent.
Further, note that each term is a decreasing function of $\zeta$, hence so is the sum of the tail, so the above inequality holds for $n$ and $\zeta$ sufficiently large.

Now combine the two parts to get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^\zeta}<1+2\varepsilon$$ for $\zeta$ sufficiently large. Since the sum is also $>1$ (trivially), we're done.

(This is basically just a reworking of the dominated convergence theorem for sums.)

Answer (score 1):

If we know that $\zeta$ is uniformly convergent then
$$\lim_s \zeta (s)=\lim_{s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_s \frac1{n^s}=1+0+0+\ldots =1.$$

Comment: Ok so since the zeta function is absolutely convergent we can take the lim inside. Then lim of $\frac{1}{n^s}$ as $s$ tends to infinity is 0. So sum of 0 is 0?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "uniformly convergent". If you mean that $1/n^s\to0$ uniformly in $n$, that's not enough to justify the fact that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. (Sums are not the same as integrals on $[a.b]$.) Not that it's hard to justify this, but "uniformly convergent" won't do it.

Comment: @Tim No, absolute convergence does not imply we can take the limit inside. What _is_ enough is this: There exist $c_n>0$ with $\sum c_n<\infty$, such that $|1/n^s|\le c_n$. (For, say, $s\ge 2$.))

Comment: Like I said, it wasn't clear to me exactly what you meant by uniform convergence. Since you mention M-tests: If you mean that the series converges uniformly (for $s\ge2$ or whatever) then yes, that's enough. That's not at all the same as the uniform convergence I was referring to in my previous comment... (see, there's convergence in two different senses going on here, either of which could be "uniform"...)

Comment: I have proved the zeta function converges uniformly on Re(s)>1+c for every c>0. Is that enough?

Comment: If you mean you've proved that that sum converges uniformly on those intervals then yes, that's enough. (No, that's not quite what you said, just as it's not quite what REr said in his answer. Saying ``\zeta'' converges is meaningless; it seems like the most natural guess what someone might mean by that is that $\zeta(s)$ converges to something as $s$ tends to something. This is not at all what either of you meant...)

Comment: Boom thanks a lot. (Everyone can ignore my first comment - since writing the sum explicitly I see $\frac{1}{1^s} +\frac{1}{2^s}+\ldots$. As s tends to infinity first term is still 1 but the rest converge to 0

Comment: I proved the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges unformly on $\Re(s)>1+c$ for every $c>0$. This is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's nice to reprove the dominated convergence theorem, we don't need to and can simply apply it:
$$
\lim_{s\to \infty} \zeta(s) = \lim_{s\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{s\to \infty} \frac1{n^s} = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty 0=1.
$$
You are allowed to interchange the limits because the series is dominated by $\zeta(2)<\infty$ for example for $s>2$.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a very simple argument. Is it flawed?

1. The magnitude of each summand is $|n^{-s}|=|n^{-\sigma-it}|=n^{-\sigma}$.
2. As $s\rightarrow\infty$ so does $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$
3. The magnitude of all the terms in the series $\zeta(s)=\sum1/n^s$ therefore  $\rightarrow 0$ except the very first which remains 1.

Therefore $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $s\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you say $s \to \infty$ as complex variable you mean $|s| \to\infty$. So this doesn't imply that $\sigma \to \infty$. So for $s$ complex to infinity, $\zeta(s)$ doesn't converge at all. It has an essential singularity at $\infty$.