# Simple proof $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

The question of proving $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$ has been posed several times. The answers seem to be overly complex - eg ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642404/how-to-prove-lim-s-rightarrow-infty-zetas-1)).

Here $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$ for complex $s=\sigma+it$.

**Question: Is the following simple argument correct?**

1. The magnitude of each summand is $|n^{-s}|=|n^{-\sigma-it}|=n^{-\sigma}$.
2. As $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$, the magnitude of all the terms in the series $\zeta(s)=\sum1/n^s$ therefore  $\rightarrow 0$ except the very first which remains 1.

Therefore $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$.

---

**EDIT:** I have corrected the question to say $\sigma \rightarrow +\infty$.

---

Comment: Why do you think you can interchange limit with series here?

Comment: The argument is certainly not complete, but it's easy to fix...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - thanks, I have corrected the question. Clearly the $\zeta(s)$ doesn't $\rightarrow 1$ for finite $1 < \sigma < \infty$.

Comment: You are essentially claiming that $$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}=1+0+0+\cdots=1. $$ As pointed out by other comments, the first step of interchanging the order of two limit operators is not possible in general. As a counter-example, we have $$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma}{(n+\sigma)^2}=1\quad\neq\quad0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\frac{\sigma}{(n+\sigma)^2}.$$ You have to ensure this kind of phenomenon do not occur in your case, or take different approach.

Comment: @SangchulLee - thanks for this insight. How do we ensure this doesn't happen here. Is it sufficient to say the series converges absolutely for $\sigma>1$ and therefore this interchanging of limit operators is ok? I am not trained to university mathematics so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Another idea is to use the Euler product formula $\zeta(s)=\prod (1-1/p^s)^-1$, where $1/p^s \rightarrow 0$ as $\sigma \rightarrow +\infty$. This would leave a product $\prod 1=1$. Does this work?

Comment: One more comment for @SangchulLee's comment. Tannery's Theorem suggests we can take the limit inside the sum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem .. is this correct?

Comment: Thinking of each summand of $\sum_n a_n(s)$ as "mass" located at $n$, the issue is often tracked down to the "mass escaping to infinity" phenomenon, that is, the collective mass is dissipated and washed away to the infinity and hence is lost under point-wise limit in $s$. A way to prevent this from happening is to ensure that the mass either only grows (as in the monotone convergence theorem) or is confined in a region of finite size (as in the dominated convergence theorem). In your case, the dominated convergence (which you are referring to Tannery's theorem) is applicable.

Comment: Yes, Tannery's Theorem is exactly what you want to fill the gap in the proof.