# Simple proof $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$ using Tannery's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

The question of proving $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$ has been posed several times.

The answers seem to be overly complex - eg ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642404/how-to-prove-lim-s-rightarrow-infty-zetas-1)).

My previous question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247955/simple-proof-zetas-rightarrow1-as-sigma-rightarrow-infty)) was not answered, but was challenged regarding the interchange of limit operators.

Here I attempt to use Tannery's Theorem ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem)) to justify the interchange of limit operators.

Here $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$ for complex $s=\sigma+it$, and $\sigma>1$.

---

**Question: Is the following simple argument correct?**

Tannery's Theorem says that

$$ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow +\infty} \sum 1/n^s = \sum \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow +\infty}  1/n^s$$

if $|1/n^s| \leq M_n$ and $\sum M_n < \infty$.

In our case $|1/n^s| \leq 1/n^{\sigma}$ and $\sum 1/n^{\sigma} < \infty$ for $\sigma>1$. Thus, the conditions for Tannery's theorem are met.

Therefore $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow +\infty$.

---

Comment: the argument is correct (it is a form of dominated/monotone convergence theorem), however if you use the doubling trick you can get the result directly in two lines as $2^{-\sigma}+3^{-\sigma} <2^{-\sigma+1}, 4^{-\sigma}+5^{-\sigma}+6^{-\sigma}+7^{-\sigma}<4^{-\sigma+1}$ etc so $0<\zeta(\sigma)-1 < \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{(-\sigma+1)n}=2^{-\sigma+1}C_{\sigma}$ with $C_{\sigma} \to 1, \sigma \to \infty$ and then $|\zeta(s)-1| \le \zeta(\sigma)-1$

Comment: hi @Conrad - thanks, where does the inequality $|\zeta(s)-1| \le \zeta(\sigma)-1$ come from?

Comment: $\zeta(s)-1=\sum_{n \ge 2}{n^{-s}}$ use triangle inequality and note that $|n^{-s}|=n^{-\sigma}$  (the inequality holds for $\sigma >1$ of course)

Comment: @Conrad - I have some doubt about the correct application of the theorem so have asked a new question about the detailed steps. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250458/riemann-zeta-zetas-rightarrow-1-as-sigma-rightarrow-infty-details-o